# Xamarin List View Selected Item Change Icon Color

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, selection

I have implemented a slider menu as ListView and can easily assign the color to any icon in the menu. However, I am trying to change the color of the ListView row that was selected (specifically the icon). I have tried using converter, but the value never changes.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="SycretBeauty.Screens.MainMenuMaster"
         Title="Master"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SycretBeauty;assembly=SycretBeauty"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SycretBeauty.Converters;assembly=SycretBeauty"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color_menu_item_background}"
         IconImageSource="images/menu.png">

    <StackLayout
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color_header_banner_background}">

        <Image
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Source="images/bannerVialang.png"
            Margin="0,30,0,20">
        </Image>

        <controls:SuperListView
            x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            HasUnevenRows="False"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            RowHeight="120"
            IsScrollingEnable="False"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color_menu_item_background}">

        <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Записаться</x:String>
                <x:String>Акции</x:String>
                <x:String>Уведомления</x:String>
                <x:String>Личный кабинет</x:String>
                <x:String>Контакты</x:String>
                <x:String>Отзывы</x:String>
                <x:String>Галерея</x:String>
                <x:String>Поделиться</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </d:ListView.ItemsSource>

        <controls:SuperListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ColumnSpacing="0">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color_menu_item_background}"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                             <controls:IconView
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HeightRequest="35"
                                Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}"
                                Source="{Binding ImgSource}">
                             </controls:IconView>             
                        </StackLayout>
            
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Text="{Binding PushCount}" 
                            IsVisible="{Binding PushUnread}"
                            d:Text="23"
                            d:IsVisible="True"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            TextColor="White"/>
            
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color_menu_item_background}"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        </StackLayout>

                        <Label Grid.Column="2"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color_menu_item_background}"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                            Text="{Binding Title}" 
                            d:Text="{Binding .}"
                            Style="{StaticResource font_menu_item_text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:SuperListView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:SuperListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the model:

```
    public class MainMenuItem
{
    public MainMenuItem()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(MainMenuItem);
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImgSource { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    public Action ItemSelected { get; set; }
    public string PushCount { get; set; }
    public bool PushUnread { get; set; }
    public Color ForegroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

And here is cs:

```
public partial class MainMenuMaster : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView;
    public AppContext Context { get; set; }

    private float rowHeight;

    public MainMenuMaster()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        ListView = MenuItemsListView;
        ListView.SizeChanged += ListView_SizeChanged;
    }


    private void ListView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var h = ListView.Height;
        rowHeight = (float)(h / 8);
        ListView.RowHeight = (int)rowHeight;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        (BindingContext as ViewModel).UpdatePushCount(Context.UnreadPushCount);
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        public ObservableCollection<MainMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public AppContext Context { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MainMenuItem>(new[]
            {
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 0,
                    ImgSource = "images/signup.png",
                    Title = "Записаться",
                    TargetType = typeof(OnlineSignupScreen),
                    ItemSelected = () => {
                        Context.SelectSalonStart(typeof(OnlineSignupScreen));
                    },
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 1,
                    ImgSource = "images/promos",
                    Title = "Акции",
                    TargetType = typeof(PromosScreen),
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray,
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 2,
                    ImgSource = "images/notify",
                    Title = "Уведомления",
                    TargetType = typeof(NotificationsScreen),
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 3,
                    ImgSource = "images/personal",
                    Title = "Личный кабинет",
                    TargetType = typeof(PersonalInfoScreen),
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 4,
                    ImgSource = "images/contacts",
                    Title = "Контакты",
                    TargetType = typeof(ContactsScreen),
                    ItemSelected = () => {
                        Context.SelectSalonStart(typeof(ContactsScreen));
                    },
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 5,
                    ImgSource = "images/feedback.png",
                    Title = "Отзывы",
                    TargetType = typeof(FeedbackScreen),
                    ItemSelected = () => {
                        Context.SelectSalonStart(typeof(FeedbackScreen));
                    },
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 6,
                    ImgSource = "images/gallery.png",
                    Title = "Галерея",
                    TargetType = typeof(GalleryScreen),
                    ItemSelected = () => {
                        Context.SelectSalonStart(typeof(GalleryScreen));
                    },
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                },
                new MainMenuItem {
                    Id = 7,
                    ImgSource = "images/share",
                    Title = "Поделиться",
                    TargetType = typeof(ShareWithFriendScreen),
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Gray
                }
            });

        }

        public void UpdatePushCount(int count)
        {
            MenuItems[2].ImgSource = count > 0 ? "images/badge" : "images/notify";
            MenuItems[2].PushCount = count.ToString();
            MenuItems[2].PushUnread = count > 0;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I also have MainMenu where I control the navigation and have ListView_onSelected method, but even there I can't change the color of the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please achieve `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for  `MainMenuItem.cs`

Then change the ForegroundColor attribute like following code.

```
 public class MainMenuItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainMenuItem()
        {
            TargetType = typeof(MainMenuItem);
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ImgSource { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
        public Action ItemSelected { get; set; }
        public string PushCount { get; set; }
        public bool PushUnread { get; set; }
      


        private Color _foregroundColor;

        public Color ForegroundColor
        {
            get { return _foregroundColor; }
            set
            {
                _foregroundColor = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");

            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I do not what is achievement about `controls:SuperListView` and `controls:IconView`, I used `listview` and `ImageButton` to replace it, If item was selected. We can change the `ImageButton`'s background color for testing.

```
  <ImageButton
           Source="{Binding ImgSource}"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           HeightRequest="35"
           BackgroundColor="{Binding ForegroundColor}"
           >
  </ImageButton>

 private void MenuItemsListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // MainMenuItem mainMenuItem = sender as MainMenuItem;

            MainMenuItem mainMenuItem = viewModel.MenuItems[e.SelectedItemIndex];
            mainMenuItem.ForegroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: I was able to set the color for the item by setting `var item = e.selectedItem` & `item.ForegroundColor = color` in `onSelected` method of the list view. But, when I select the other element in the list view, the color stays on the previously selected row. How to "deselect" other elements when I change the selected menu item?

Comment: You can add the `IsSelect` property in your Model(Please achieve format like `ForegroundColor`). When execute the `MenuItemsListView_ItemSelected` method, you can judge the value of `IsSelect`,  if the value is true, you can set one color, if the value is false, you can set the another color.

Comment: Thanks it is working perfectly, but I noticed that on Android when I change between pages, the selectors don't change in master menu. is there a way to achieve this?